# If $M$ is non-singular and $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$, then prove that $(MA)^\dagger MA = A^\dagger A.$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $M$ is non-singular and $A\in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$,then prove that $(MA)^\dagger MA = A^\dagger A.$ ($A^\dagger$ is the Moore Penrose inverse of } $A$).

If we will prove $(MA)^\dagger = A^\dagger M^{-1}$ then it is done.

I proceed by the four properties of Moore Penrose:

(i) $MAA^\dagger M^{-1}MA = MAA^\dagger A = MA$

(ii) $A^\dagger M^{-1}MAA^\dagger M^{-1} = A^\dagger AA^\dagger M^{-1} = A^\dagger M^{-1}$

(iii) $(A^\dagger M^{-1}MA)^T = (A^\dagger A)^T = A^\dagger A = A^\dagger M^{-1}MA$

How to show this fourth property:

(iv) $(MAA^\dagger M^{-1})^T = MAA^\dagger M^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you're attempting as you "proceed by the four properties."  However, here's a quick proof:

It suffices to note that $A^\dagger A$ is the orthogonal projection onto the row-space of $A$ (i.e. the range of $A^T$).  From there, it suffices to note that $MA$ has the same row-space, which means that $(MA)^\dagger(MA)$ is this same orthogonal projection.  So, $(MA)^\dagger(MA) = A^\dagger A$.